Replacing specific character seq in Kotlin
Need to replace a String that looks like this "xxxx-xxxx" with a given Long, so input output:
"33" -> "xxxx-xx33"
"884433 -> "xx88-4433"
"0" -> "xxxx-xxx0"
They need to get added from the end.
There's a few ways to do this, such as adding zeros to the input, then the dashes, but I'm wondering if there's a Kotlin way to do with replace?

Have you considered NumberFormat?  (I don't know whether that could support the unconverted xs, but if not, it could presumably give you spaces that you could then convert.)

You can achieve this in Kotlin using the replace method combined with a regular expression. Here's how you can do it:
fun replaceWithLong(input: String, longValue: Long): String {
val longString = longValue.toString().padStart(8, '0') // Convert Long to String and pad with zeros
val pattern = "x{4}-x{4}".toRegex() // Pattern to match "xxxx-xxxx"

return pattern.replaceFirst("xxxx-xxxx") {
    longString.substring(0, 4) + "-" + longString.substring(4)
}}
fun main() {
println(replaceWithLong("xxxx-xxxx", 33))       // Output: "xxxx-xx33"
println(replaceWithLong("xxxx-xxxx", 884433))   // Output: "xx88-4433"
println(replaceWithLong("xxxx-xxxx", 0))}       // Output: "xxxx-xxx0"


longValue.toString().padStart(8, '0'): This converts the Long value to a String and pads it with leading zeros to ensure it's always 8 characters long.
"x{4}-x{4}".toRegex(): This creates a regular expression that matches the pattern "xxxx-xxxx".
replaceFirst with lambda: The replaceFirst method is used to replace the first match of the pattern. The lambda function splits the padded longString into two parts and formats them as "xxxx-xxxx".

This solution ensures the Long value is added to the string from the end, replacing the appropriate "x" characters.
